# Does the larger tail dependence implies a larger positive dependence?

Tags: independence, copula

For Archimedean copula such as Clayton and Gumbel, their positive dependence can be measured by Kendall's $\tau$ that $\tau_\textrm{Clayton} = \frac{\theta}{\theta + 2}, \tau_\textrm{Gumbel} = 1-\frac1{\theta}$. And Their tail dependence is $\lambda_L = 2^{-\frac1{\theta}}, \lambda_U = 2-2^{-\frac1{\theta}}$. From an intuitive observation, it can be seen that the positive dependence between these two copula increases with increasing tail dependence.

Does there exist a more general conclusion about the larger tail dependence implies a larger positive dependence?

Comment: Imagine a sequence of copulas where tail dependence increases as you go along the sequence but the dependence other than in the tails moved the opposite direction...